# How to use TABLESAMPLE on filtered query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to query random rows from a table with specified filters. I am using `TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(n)` to get `n` percent of rows.

I am able to filter the result, but the problem is that if the random sample doesn't include desired data (it might happen when there is little data) I get no data in the result.

This is what I was running:

```
SELECT id from table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(10) WHERE age < 20 LIMIT 30;
```

I would like to be able to first filter the table and then get random samples. I would expect the query to look like this:

```
SELECT id from table WHERE age < 20 TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(10) LIMIT 30;
```

but this is not a valid syntax.

My question is: Is there a way to use TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI after filtering the data?

Comment: I'd also like to know this 

Comment: I think you can put the filtered table into a temp table and then query that?

Answer (score 1):

Nathan is right. The section [TABLESAMPLE Clause Restrictions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html) in the postgres docs states:

> The TABLESAMPLE clause is currently accepted only on regular tables and materialized views. According to the SQL standard it should be possible to apply it to any FROM item.

You could write your query like this:

```sql
create temp table tbl_filtered as select id from table where age < 20;
select id from tbl_filtered tablesample bernoulli(10) limit 30;
```